# Android Handling orientation changes - no change if rotation occurs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem dealing with orientation.

I have a fragment in an activity that loads when I run the app.

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
```

Output:(default orientation - portrait)

[image]

However when I rotate the phone into landscape, it just adds up the fragment.

Output :

[image]

Is there any way that I can fix this? I've been reading some questions about dealing rotations on run time, but their solutions are to disable the orientation. Some also say that to use AsyncTask functions on dealing with this matter. I am new on android and I am not yet familiar to other android libraries. Thanks for answering.

Comment: What do you mean by it just adds up the fragment?

Comment: Remove the fragment on onPause() or onDestroy().

Comment: @MalithLakshan while this may avoid repeating the fragment, it will cause issues when trying to save/restore that fragment's state since you are creating a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen rotation will not destroy your previous fragment, instead saving and restoring it's state.

I'm guessing you call that `fragmentTransaction` logic inside your Activity's `onCreate` method, so each time the activity is restored it is adding a new fragment on top of the old one(s).

You can prevent this by checking if the `savedInstanceState` Bundle is null on your `onCreate()` method, that way you won't add a new fragment if your activity is being recreated like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new HomeFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.